# Finding the source of a large amount of data added to hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, search

Basically, a few days ago a saw that my C drive randomly went from 17 GB free to 1 GB free and I'm trying to find the source of it. Windows search using datecreated or datemodified is quite cumbersome to use; is there any program out there that can analyze this and show data such as large allocation of hard drive space in a small amount of time?

Comment: what programs or processes are you running?

Comment: This can be caused by updates downloading and still not applied,or temporary files, however nowadays you need to pay close attention as this is one of the signs of ransomware encrypting hard files, not to alarm you but dont discard it as something to look into.

Answer (score 3):

Grab something like [WinDirStat](http://www.windirstat.info).  Anything taking up 16 GB as a single file or as a folder should stand out fairly readily.

Answer (score 0):

It could well be your Windows 10 upgrade. Even though you probably declined the upgrade, Microsoft will download it anyway ('so you have it when you want it').

The already recommended procedures will help you to identify the files' location. There is little sense in simply deleting them though, as Windows will just download them again for you (how nice of Microsoft).

I cannot produce the complete details here, but there's ways to prohibit it. Google 'avoid Windows 10 download'.